Predicting Millstones
I have data detailing specific projects going on and when they achieved certain milestones. I'm trying to predict the end date of the project based on these milestone dates. An example of the dates would be:
ID  Milestone 1 Milestone 2 Milestone 3 End Date
1   08-10-2022  08-24-2022  09-25-2022  10-08-2022
2   09-15-2022  10-10-2022  10-25-2022  11-04-2022
3   08-17-2022  9-10-2022   10-01-2022  10-26-2022
I have other variables available as well however such as the location of the project but these have shown to be far less powerful.
The difficulty comes in when putting this model into practice. When predicting the end date on projects in progress then they may not have reached all the milestones. In order to simulate this, I have found the average durations between the milestones, found the proportion of missing milestones in my live data, and then artificially removed that amount from my modeling data, and inserted the sum of the previous non-missing milestone dates plus the average durations to create imputed milestone dates for those that are missing. I then converted all of these dates to ordinal and created several models.
The results were pretty good, and I achieved a mean absolute error averaged across 3 folds of cross-validation of about 12 days. However, when I went to put this into practice on the live (not the modeling) data I noticed that the vast majority of my predicted End Dates were all falling behind my milestone 3 and all were behind todays date despite these projects being in progress.
This made me realize the naivety of my process... By using modeling data where the largest end date can only be up to todays date then my predictions on live data will not likely exceed this which is the entire point of the model.
So, now that I've realized my error, what would you all suggest I do instead? I've considered using the duration between the milestones but that would likely just end up being the last milestone date that occurred, plus the average duration to the end date. This doesn't produce phenomenal results in my testing, is that all I can hope to achieve? Any alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Your title refers to millstones while your body text talks about milestones, which is not at all the same thing. It appears you mean the latter. Please fix your question.

Why did you repost rather than edit the original?
